# GeoServer REST API - get layergroups

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

I am writing a small python script to check configuration on my Geoserver.

To get a list of layers/services on the geoserver I use:

```
url = 'geoserverIP/geoserver/rest/layers.json'


response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password))
data = response.json()
```

That part works properly, but when I try to get a list of group layers, I get an empty json, but I expected group1,... to be shown in json

```
url = 'geoserverIP/geoserver/rest/layergroups.json'
```

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have an idea where might be a problem?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Your current endpoint
[Displays a list of all layer groups on the server not otherwise in a workspace](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/layergroups.yaml)

What you might need is

```py
url = 'geoserverIP/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{workspace}/layergroups.json'
```